# Exporting R tables to HTML

Tags: html, r, export

Is there a way to easily export R tables to a simple HTML page?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `xtable` function in the `xtable` package can export R tables to HTML tables. [This blog entry](http://www.r-bloggers.com/create-odf-pdf-and-html-report-from-a-single-sweave-document/) describes how you can create HTML pages from Sweave documents.

Comment: `print(xtable(tb), type = "html")`, to be precise. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @DavidB Based on the others' comments, you can use this code `print(xtable(tb), type = "html",file = 'myfile.html')` whhere you can find the exported file in your work directory.

Answer (score 21):

It might be worth mentioning that there has been a new package specifically designed to convert (and style with css) data.frames (or tables) into HTML tables in an easy and intuitive way. It is called `tableHTML`. You can see a simple example below:

```
library(tableHTML)
#create an html table 
tableHTML(mtcars)

#and to export in a file
write_tableHTML(tableHTML(mtcars), file = 'myfile.html')
```

You can see a detailed tutorial [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html) as well.

Answer (score 13):

Apart from `xtable` mentioned by @nullglob there are three more packages that might come handy here:

- [R2HTML](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2HTML/index.html)
- [HTMLUtils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HTMLUtils/index.html)
- [hwriter](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hwriter/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of tables package [gt](https://gt.rstudio.com/index.html) is also an option.

Here's the [example](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/as_raw_html.html) from the docs for generating a HTML table:

```
library(gt)

tab_html <-
  gtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(mfr, model, msrp) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:5) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("Data listing from **gtcars**"),
    subtitle = md("`gtcars` is an R dataset")
  ) %>%
  as_raw_html()
```

Answer (score 0):

[In an issue for the DT package, someone posted how to use the DT package to get html in tables](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/989). I've pasted the relevant example code, modifying it to reference all columns with: `targets = "_all"`.

```
library(DT)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'sort'){",
  "    var parser = new DOMParser();",
  "    var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');",
  "    data = doc.querySelector('a').innerText;",
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)

dat <- data.frame(
  a = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), 
  b = c(
    '<a href="#" id = "Z" onclick = "Ztest">aaaaa</a>', 
    '<a href="#" id = "A" onclick = "Atest">bbbbb</a>',
    '<a href="#" id = "J" onclick = "Jtest">jjjjj</a>'
  )
)

datatable(
  dat, 
  escape = FALSE,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = "_all", render = JS(render))
    )
  )
)
```

I hope this helps.