# exporting table in R to HTML with hyperlinks

Tags: html, r

While this question more generally has been looked at here:

[Exporting R tables to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438226/exporting-r-tables-to-html)

I was wondering specifically how to have text in a data frame appear as a hyperlink in the .html file.  I am using the `R2HTML` package.

```
foo <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), 
url=c('http://nytimes.com', 'http://cnn.com', 'http://www.weather.gov'))


HTML(foo, file='foo.html')
```

In the above example, I'd like the `http://nytimes.com`, etc. to appear as hyperlinks in the `foo.html` file.

Apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution using `googleVis`

```
foo <- transform(foo, url = paste('<a href = ', shQuote(url), '>', url, '</a>')) 
x = gvisTable(foo, options = list(allowHTML = TRUE))
plot(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!  Your use use of transform is what did the trick.  I can then use `HTML(foo, file='bar.html')` and it displays properly.  Additionally, thanks for sharing your tip with `gvisTable`, very nice.  Using `print(x, file='bar.html')` gives the desired result.

Comment: Question about `gvisTable()`.  Is there a way to change the parameters so that the number of rows and columns displayed changes as you resize the browser window?