# How can I turn a column of urls into links in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and one of the columns is all urls. I am trying to turn them into links that display as "link". My homework assignment says that I should use the format `[link](url)`, but it doesn't work for me to include my column name. How can I mutate my dataframe to turn the urls into links?

Comment: Is that a shiny app where you want clickable links? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155382/putting-hyperlinks-into-an-html-table-in-r) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315372/rshiny-how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink) could help.

Comment: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_basics.html `[linked phrase](http://example.com)` becomes [linked phrase](http://example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample Shiny app that will take a set of URLs and then display them as clickable links.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("myoutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  require(DT)

  myNames <- c("Google", "Facebook")
  myURLs <- c("https://google.com", "https://facebook.com")

  output$myoutput <- renderDataTable(escape = FALSE, {
    df <- data.frame(Site_Name = myNames, Site_URL = myURLs )
    df$Site_URL <- sapply(df$Site_URL, function(x)
      toString(tags$a(href = x, x)))
    df
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is lacking any explanation and doesn't seem to answer the question.