# Analysis of deviance table model output in HTML

Tags: html, r, glm, stargazer

I am trying to export the output of an 'Analysis of deviance table' in HTML format, so that it can be inserted into a word document.

I created a GLM model as follows:

```
newmod <- glm(cbind(Recaptured, predated) ~ Morph * Plant * Site, data = 
survival, family = binomial)
```

Running the following code gives me the output that I would like to export to HTML:

```
anova(newmod,test="Chisq")
```

I have tried the following code to create a HTML table using stargazer, however it doesn't seem to be working:

```
anova_mod<-anova(newmod,test="Chisq")
stargazer(newmod, type="html", out = "anova_output.htm")
```

Is there a simple way of doing this in r? I have managed to successfully export the summary statistics, but what I really need is the Analysis of deviance table.

Comment: I have found a solution to this issue now, I turned the model output (the analysis of deviance table) into a matrix using as.matrix(), I was then able to use stargazer on that object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for:

`print(xtable(anova_mod), type = "html")`

as indicated by this answer: [Exporting R tables to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438226/exporting-r-tables-to-html)

Here is my full code for reproducing something similar to your question:

```
plant.df = PlantGrowth
plant.df$group = factor(plant.df$group,labels = c("Control", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2"))
newmod = lm(weight ~ group, data = plant.df)
anova_mod=anova(newmod)
anova_mod

install.packages("xtable")
require(xtable)
print(xtable(anova_mod), type = "html")
```

You can then paste the output to an html vizualizer such as: https://htmledit.squarefree.com/ to see the resulting table.

Instead of printing it, you can write it to a file. I have not personally tested this part, but the second answer in this question should work for you: [Save html result to a txt or html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463236/save-html-result-to-a-txt-or-html-file)

Note: You can also reference all parts of the `anova_mod` separately by adding a `$` after it like `anova_mod$Df`.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this works either :( because although I can't save the data to a file (I didn't figure that part out yet), the data that is printed is not from the 'analysis of deviance' table, it is just the summary statistics...

Comment: @DebbieWalsh I did not read your question correctly the first time. Your `newmod` variable should be your model. Since you want the analysis of deviance, then you should export the information from the `anova_mod` variable. My answer gets an update to reflect that.